# Can Spark SQL push down a LIMIT operator on inner join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

Spark SQL doesn't seem to be able to push down LIMIT operators on inner joined tables. This is an issue when joining large tables to extract a small subset of rows. I'm testing on Spark 2.2.1 (most recent release).

Below is a contrived example, which runs in the `spark-shell` (Scala):

First, set up the tables:

```
case class Customer(id: Long, name: String, email: String, zip: String)
case class Order(id: Long, customer: Long, date: String, amount: Long)

val customers = Seq(
  Customer(0, "George Washington", "gwashington@usa.gov", "22121"),
  Customer(1, "John Adams", "gwashington@usa.gov", "02169"),
  Customer(2, "Thomas Jefferson", "gwashington@usa.gov", "22902"),
  Customer(3, "James Madison", "gwashington@usa.gov", "22960"),
  Customer(4, "James Monroe", "gwashington@usa.gov", "22902")
)

val orders = Seq(
  Order(1, 1, "07/04/1776", 23456),
  Order(2, 3, "03/14/1760", 7850),
  Order(3, 2, "05/23/1784", 12400),
  Order(4, 3, "09/03/1790", 6550),
  Order(5, 4, "07/21/1795", 2550),
  Order(6, 0, "11/27/1787", 1440)
)

import spark.implicits._

val customerTable = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(customers).toDS()
customerTable.createOrReplaceTempView("customer")

val orderTable = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(orders).toDS()
orderTable.createOrReplaceTempView("order")
```

Now run the following join query, with a LIMIT and an arbitrary filter for each joined table:

```
scala> val join = spark.sql("SELECT c.* FROM customer c JOIN order o ON c.id = o.customer WHERE c.id > 1 AND o.amount > 5000 LIMIT 1")
```

Then print the corresponding optimized execution plan:

```
scala> println(join.queryExecution.sparkPlan.toString)
CollectLimit 1
+- Project [id#5L, name#6, email#7, zip#8]
   +- SortMergeJoin [id#5L], [customer#17L], Inner
      :- Filter (id#5L > 1)
      :  +- SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$Customer, true]).id AS id#5L, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$Customer, true]).name, true) AS name#6, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$Customer, true]).email, true) AS email#7, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$Customer, true]).zip, true) AS zip#8]
      :     +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#4]
      +- Project [customer#17L]
         +- Filter ((amount#19L > 5000) && (customer#17L > 1))
            +- SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$Order, true]).id AS id#16L, assertnotnull(input[0, $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$Order, true]).customer AS customer#17L, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$Order, true]).date, true) AS date#18, assertnotnull(input[0, $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$Order, true]).amount AS amount#19L]
               +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#15]
```

and you can immediately see that both tables are sorted in their entirety before being joined (although for these small example tables the explicit `Sort` step is not shown before the `SortMergeJoin`), and only afterward is the LIMIT applied.

If one of the databases contains billions of rows, this query becomes extremely slow and resource intensive, *regardless of the LIMIT size*.

Is Spark capable of optimizing such a query? Or can I work around the issue without mangling my SQL beyond recognition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark 3.0 adds `LimitPushDown` so from that version it will be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is Spark capable of optimizing such a query

In short, it is not.

Using old nomenclature, `join` is a wide a transformation, where each output partition depends on every upstream partition. As a result, both parent datasets have to be fully scanned, to compute even a single partition of the child.

It is not impossible that some optimizations will be included in the future, however if you goal is to:

> extract a small subset of rows.

then you should consider using database, not Apache Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will be helpful in your use case, but did you consider adding the filter and limit clause in order table itself.

> val orderTableLimited = orderTable.filter($"customer" >
>   1).filter($"amount" > 5000).limit(1)

Comment: this will not push down to the sql